# Flutter Web Page Refresh and 404 Not Found Error

Tags: flutter, routes, http-status-code-404, refresh

In the main method i used UrlStrategy package as seen in the below because i don't want # in my urls:

```
void main() {
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

In the debug mode when i tested the website, there was no problem. Then i published my website. The homepage is like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and when i tried to refresh the page with F5, there is no problem. Then i navigate to another page like [www.example.com/about-us](http://www.example.com/about-us) and try to refresh page with F5 again, and i get "404 not found" error.

To solve this i created .htaccess file in htdocs and wrote inside of this file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewritwCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewritwCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

But i started to get 500 Internal Server Error.

There was an existing .htaccess file outside of htdocs. I copied the code above and pasted it inside of existing .htaccess. But again same problem. The codes in existing .htaccess file is given in below:

```
##################################################
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# Create a new .htaccess file in your htdocs
# directory (or example.com/htdocs/ directory)
# to add your own rules or override these rules.
#
##################################################

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index2.html

ErrorDocument 403 https://infinityfree.net/errors/403/
ErrorDocument 404 https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/
ErrorDocument 500 https://infinityfree.net/errors/500/
```

What i have to do?

Answer (score 8):

I created a file called .htaccess in htdocs. And I pasted the codes given below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]
```

The problem is solved.

Comment: Is this the only code you have in your htaccess? And can you explain why you modified the code from above like this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This code was the only code. But then i added some more codes for https too. And unfortunately i cannot explain the reason of modifications because i don't know the reason. I checked some repositories and i saw such solutions. Just i tried them and i solved my problem. The whole code inside htaccess is:

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !{"scheme":"https"}

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]




RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below if you're using nginx instead of apache.

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your nginx conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

and remove or comment out

> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;