# Flutter Web Page Refresh and 404 Not Found Error on Subdomain at hostinger. This problem was solved, but its not working for subdomain

Tags: flutter, .htaccess, subdomain, hosting

When the page is refreshed it shows 404 Not found. I want it to work as normal. When files are hosted to a domain after adding a .htaccess file it works. But when hosting to a subdomain it's not working.

No solution is working for a subdomain.
My Files are in root/book/

I tried this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72147109/13813009

`RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !{"scheme":"https"}  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  RewriteEngine On  RewriteBase /book/ RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png)  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]`

and

`RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png) RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]`

and with book base

`RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /book RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png) RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check this now.